# How much space will Mathematica, Maple, and Matlab take up?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, matlab, mathematica, maple

I as wondering how much space Mathematica, Maple, and Matlab will take up, under Windows and under Ubuntu? I am planning to reserve some space in partitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica requires 4GB on any platform ([Link](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/features/system-requirements.html#Windows))

Maple requires 1GB on Windows and 2GB on Ubuntu ([Link](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/system_requirements.aspx))

Matlab States it requires `1 GB for MATLAB only, 3–4 GB for a typical installation`, on both Windows and Linux ([Link](http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html))

FYI - I used to partition everything, now I don't bother. Forget partitions, it just becomes a nightmare to manage at a later date!

Comment: Thanks! (1) "I used to partition everything," do you mean make a partition for each big software? (2)I plan to install the softwares with the OS on the same partition. Is that good or there is some better way?

Comment: @Tim - it is just personal choice. I used to have one for downloads, one for games, one for apps, one for OS and one for documents... I just find it so easier to have everything on one. You can never plan in advance what you may do and having one just makes it much easier to manage (In my opinion)

Comment: There's such a thing as too many partitions, I usually try to keep just two: One for "system" (OS, apps, etc..) and a separate one for "user" data (everything under `/home`). But yeah, it's a pain if you estimate the sizes wrong...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - I agree I used to do far too many! Obviously now, resizing is also easier (still annoying with loads of partitions), and I still like the idea in theory... but, every time I have done it, I live to regret it!

Answer (score 2):

Since Mathematica 6, but especially with Mathematica 8, using certain functionalities such as curated data (for Chemicals, Geography, Polyhedra, etc.) will load and update local databases from the Wolfram internet web sites. Expect the footprint of the program to grow over time. Usually the first use since install of one of these functions will cause a significant first download and indexing before it answers.